# Getting Closest Hidden Value Outside TR

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get the the value of the hidden field with the class "OriginalSuggestedQty" when a checkbox within the row is checked?

Here is what the HTML looks like:

```
<input class="OriginalSuggestedQty" type="hidden" value="5">
<tr>
    <td >
        <input class="SuggestedQty" id="items_1__SuggestedQty" type="text" value="9">
        <input checked="checked" class="suggested"type="checkbox" value="true">
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is what i currently have:

```
$(".suggested").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        var originalVal = $(this).closest('.OriginalSuggestedQty').val();
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.SuggestedQty').val(originalVal);
    }
});
```

Comment: The posted HTML is invalid. Also what is failing with your example code?

Comment: Can you provide more of the html?

Comment: That is how it looks though. The hidden inputs are at the same level as the tr's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the exact HTML shown in the post, you can use this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').prev()
```

That will step up until it reaches the TR and then select the immediately preceding DOM element, which is the input.
Is this correct or will you have other elements between the TR and the input?

Answer (score 1):

If the HTML has the same structure throughout your page.

so:

```
input
table > tbody > tr > td > checkbox
```

I wouldn't use jQuery (pretty heavy functions, with lots of iterations) to do such a simple DOM traversal:

Just do this:

```
$(".suggested").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      //refer to this, without jQuery wrapper
      var originalVal = $(this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.previousElementSibling.querySelector("input.OriginalSuggestedQty")).val();
  }
 }
```

This will select the input by going up to parents (great-great-grandparent `table`), select its brother that is before him `previousElementSibling` (prevent selecting of textnodes), then use `querySelector` to select the correct element.

Finally wrap it in a jQuery-object to allow jQuery ninja to be performed.

However I would use an alternative solution:

Your inputs all have an `id`: `items_1__SuggestedQty`. Why not give every input a corresponding data-id attribute:

```
<input class="OriginalSuggestedQty" data-id="items_1__SuggestedQty"  type="hidden" value="5">
```

Now you can select easily by doing this:

```
$(".suggested").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
       var originalVal = $("input[data-id='"+$(this).prev().attr("id")+"']").val();
       $(this).closest('tr').find('.SuggestedQty').val(originalVal);
    }
});
```

`input[data-id='"+$(this).prev().attr("id")+"']"` this bit will select the element that contains a data-attribute matching the id of the input that is adjacent to the checkbox. This way the link between the elements is more robust. If in the future something changes in the HTML structure the bond will not be broken.

Comment: I am getting this error :  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null

Comment: @user3788671 What version of IE do you need to support?

Comment: @user3788671, you do need to adept this code to your HTML code, You cannot do a one on one copy since we don't have your full HTML code.

Comment: Thank you for trying. When I used the latest answer the value was pulling an undefined.