# Getting Closest Hidden Value Outside TR table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamic table where inside the `tbody` before each `tr`, I have an input, and I want to get this value using javascript or jquery.

```
<input  id="formID" type="hidden" value="records.get(i).getFormID">  
    <tr>
        <td><%=records.get(i).getCensusYear()%></td>
        <td> Approved </td>
        <td><%=records.get(i).getApprovedByName()%> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> <input align="center" id ="clickedTable" class="btn btn-flat btn-success" style="margin: 0 auto 5% auto" type="button" value="View Table"/></td>
        <td> <input align="center" id= "clickedChart" class="btn btn-flat btn-success" style="margin: 0 auto 5% auto"  type="button" value="View Chart"/></td>
   </tr>
```

When the button is clicked, i want to get the value of the `input`. I already used `closest, prev and find` but it wont work. Also I tried the answer in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29128016/getting-closest-hidden-value-outside-tr) but it still won't work.

```
 $('#clickedTable, #clickedChart').click(function () {
    if (this.id == 'clickedTable') {
        document.getElementById('clicked').setAttribute('value', "table");
        var $item =   alert($(this).closest('tr').prev('input').attr('formID'));
        var $item =   alert($(this).prev('input').attr('formID'));

        alert($item);;

        document.getElementById('archivedView').submit();
     } else if (this.id == 'clickedChart') {
             document.getElementById('clicked').setAttribute('value', "chart");
             var $item = $(this).closest('tr').prev();
             document.getElementById('formID').setAttribute('value', $item);
             document.getElementById('archivedView').submit();
     }
   });`
```

Above code keeps on returning undefined values.

Comment: Problem is -> when browser renders page, all `<input />` tags are pushed out of table. and you CAN'T use same IDS!

Comment: `inside the tbody before each tr, I have an input,` this makes you html invalid. only child of table is tr then td then you can have your input here

Comment: thanks for the advice, i will try to find another way to this

Comment: show full code, including dynamic bits.... so a solution can be worked; ie you should be able to add an id to the button and lnk it to the input via the same id, but without a full context of what is going on. I cant really help.

Comment: you could simply solve this by putting it in a hidden input into a hidden td in the tr #justsaying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT - Since you're using dataTables, you can do something like:**

**html:**

```
<table id="t">...</table>
```

**jquery:**

```
myData = [
    ["James", "1997", "<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"funcX('someData')\""],
    ["Peter", "2003", "<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"funcX('someOtherData')\""]
]; //can be from any other source (read dataTables docs)

$('#t').DataTable( {
        data: myData,
        columns: [
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Year" },
            { title: "" } //your input button
        ]
} );

function funcX(arg) { ... }
```

Comment: it is a dynamic table.

Comment: @SCS. I know. `myValue` in `func1` and `2` would be dynamic. This for example (using php) : `foreach($myArray as $myValue) { echo '<td><input onclick=func1(". $myValue . ')" ...></td> ... }`.

Comment: i am planning to use `dataTables` for sorting and so on, having a hidden input in `td` would not make the DataTables work :( @kajoh